# How do I load more table rows while scrolling?

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, erb

My guess is that I must add a 'post do' statement to my .rb file, though I'm still new to Sinatra and unfamiliar with how to load more content once the browser has scrolled to the bottom of the page.

Here's an example of my .rb file:

```
get '/' do
  @arr = []
  (1..1000).each{ |x| @arr << x }
  erb :test
end
```

And here's an example of my .erb file:

```
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr><td>Number</td></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @arr.each do |number| %>
    <tr><td><%= number %></td></tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Of course, I wouldn't want all 1,000 rows to load. Instead, it would nice for just the first 10 to load, then the next 10 when the user scrolls to the bottom, and so on.

Does anyone know how I can learn this for Sinatra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Sinatra, but you can embed Javascript functions that fire on scroll events.

[Javascript onscroll event help](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php)

Comment: Hm, I figured it had something to do with JavaScript. My only concern is that I have lots of data that my script processes. In my example, for instance, would the script process only process the first 10 numbers for the user? Or would it process all of them, then show the first 10?

Comment: Sadly, I am a little out of my depth with your code, since I am unfamiliar with Sinatra. However, I would venture a guess that it depends on how you set up your JS events.